# How to compare 2 field in table and make status field

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How do I write a query to compare 2 fields and make status?

the table is as follows

I tried this code:

```sql
select a, b , if ( a=b,'true','false') as status from x
```

I want the result like

```
a | b | status 
A | A | True
A | B | False
A | C | False
B | B | true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html):

```
select
 a, b,
 case when trim(a) = trim(b) then 'True' else 'False' end status
from x
```

There is also the function [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html):

```
select
 a, b,
 if(trim(a) = trim(b), 'True', 'False') status
from x
```

Comment: Change the names of the columns from a and b to pilihan and jawaban

Comment: Maybe there are spaces in the columns. See my edited answer

Comment: sure i was try it but is same . it be all false like the image in my link ufile.io/4vcoi

Comment: Did you try trim()?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **case**,

```
select f1,f2,case when(f1=f2) then 'True' else 'False' end as 'Status' from t1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0c89718d51606b97ad11ca7881a09898)

**CASE statement**

> The CASE statement goes through conditions and return a value when the
>   first condition is met (like an IF-THEN-ELSE statement). So, once a
>   condition is true, it will stop reading and return the result.
>
> If no conditions are true, it will return the value in the ELSE
>   clause.
>
> If there is no ELSE part and no conditions are true, it returns NULL